# How to select a row in MySQL if meets condition, and select another row if condition is not met?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this, we'll call the table `foo`:

```
+----+------------+----------+----------+
| id | product_id |   name   | language |
+----+------------+----------+----------+
|  1 |          1 | Potatoes | English  |
|  2 |          1 | Patatas  | Spanish  |
|  3 |          3 | Bananas  | English  |
+----+------------+----------+----------+
```

As you may be able to tell, rows 1 and 2 are the same product, with row 2 being a translation of row 1.

I want to select row 2 and row 3. The reason for this is that by selecting row 2 and row 3 I've selected all products in my table (without duplicates). I want to select row 2 instead of row 1, because I have a "language preference" for Spanish - I want to select the row containing the Spanish translation where possible. In the event that a Spanish translation is not available (i.e. product 3), we simply select the English version (or, the version where the `product_id` is equal to the `id` column).

How can I approach this in MySQL? I've currently got this, which selects all the English rows, but I would like to apply a condition to the `WHERE` part, as mentioned above.

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE product_id = id
```

Comment: is this sorted out now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select f.*
from foo f
where f.language = 'Spanish'
union all
select f.*
from foo f
where f.language = 'English' and
      not exists (select 1 from foo f2 where f2.product_id = f.product_id and f2.language = 'Spanish');
```

This selects all foo rows in English.  And then rows in Spanish that do not match.

Comment: Great answer; I definitely didn't think of that, thanks for that - but I think you've got the order mixed up; I want Spanish as the highest priority, English as second priority... just judging from a glance, haven't tested, but is yours the other way round?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is: place the default name, that is english name, in table `foo`.

All other names, e.g. Spanish, in a separate table(like `foo_I18N`)